# How find nodes, which have relation with list of start nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have list of start nodes (Ingridients) and i want find all recipes, which have specified ingridients (code sample below).
I'm trying find all recipes with contain ingridients 'Ingridient2', 'Ingridient3','Ingridient4'.

I use this code

```
MATCH result=(n:Ingridient)-[r:RELATED]->(m:Recipe)
  WHERE n.name IN ['Ingridient2', 'Ingridient3','Ingridient4']
RETURN result
```

But this code return all recipe which contain only one Ingridient2 or Ingridient3, etc.

My question how i can find recipes, with contain specified Ingridients.
Also link attached with example http://console.neo4j.org/r/doxwy4

```
CREATE (Recipe1:Recipe {name:'Recipe1'})
CREATE (Recipe2:Recipe {name:'Recipe2'})
CREATE (Recipe3:Recipe {name:'Recipe3'})
CREATE (Recipe4:Recipe {name:'Recipe4'})

CREATE (Ingridient1:Ingridient {name:'Ingridient1'})
CREATE (Ingridient2:Ingridient {name:'Ingridient2'})
CREATE (Ingridient3:Ingridient {name:'Ingridient3'})
CREATE (Ingridient4:Ingridient {name:'Ingridient4'})
CREATE (Ingridient5:Ingridient {name:'Ingridient5'})

CREATE
  (Ingridient1)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe1),
  (Ingridient2)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe1),
  (Ingridient3)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe1)

CREATE
  (Ingridient2)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe2),
  (Ingridient3)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe2),
  (Ingridient4)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe2)

CREATE
  (Ingridient3)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe3),
  (Ingridient4)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe3),
  (Ingridient5)-[:RELATED]->(Recipe3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Cypher, with comments, for what you want to do. You can use WHERE ALL(...) to validate on an entire collection.

```
// Match all Recipe and their ingredients
MATCH (n:Ingridient)-[r:RELATED]->(recipe:Recipe)

// Collect ingredients into a collection
WITH COLLECT(n.name) as ingredients, recipe

// Filter where recipe uses all our ingredients
WHERE ALL(part in ['Ingridient2', 'Ingridient3','Ingridient4'] WHERE part IN ingridients)

// Return valid recipes
RETURN recipe
```

Comment: yeah, you my lifesaver. but correct typo in ingridients (should ingredients)

Comment: @BekerovArtur You used "Ingridient" in your question, so I kept the Cypher consistent with that =P